# Path error while installing react-native (Command not found error)

Tags: facebook, react-native

I am trying to install react-native. I have followed all the steps here:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

When I use this command :

```
react-native newProject
```

I am getting error as:

```
-bash: react-native: command not found.
```

I think incorrect path is the source of this error, but I don't know how to correct it. Any help is greatly appreciated

I have taken a look at this question but couldn't follow:[Error when installed react-native-cli command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767729/error-when-installed-react-native-cli-command-not-found)

Comment: Have you installed react-native using the -g option?

Comment: yes i have installed with the -g option

Comment: Did you install any of the components (homebrew, io.js, nvm, react-native) with sudo / su?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched extensively and a few possible errors that could solve this issue is:

1. update and upgrade brew(the latter takes quite some time so be patient)
2. uninstall and re-install node-npm(brew install node)

After you re-install npm/node restart your computer,

3. npm install -g react-native-cli (install the cli stuff again now)

Now it should work

I think reinstalling node worked for me(remember to reboot the system)

Hope this helps