# -bash: npm: command not found error message when installing React Native CLI on Mac

Tags: react-native

I'm following the latest instructions 05/31/2017 on installing React Native on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content. 
I'm attempting to install react-native. I successfully installed Homebrew, Node, Watchman but when I tried installing React Native CLI with this command:

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

it gave me this error message:

`-bash: npm: command not found`.

I then used this command:
`curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

and the terminal gave me this message: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYe5Y.png)

I then tried running this code:

`react-native init AwesomeProject`

but got this error message:

`-bash: react-native: command not found`

can someone help me overcome this obstacle so I can successfully installing React Native CLI? Thank you.

I already checked out the following but to no avail:

[Error when installed react-native-cli command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767729/error-when-installed-react-native-cli-command-not-found)

[Path error while installing react-native (Command not found error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253981/path-error-while-installing-react-native-command-not-found-error)

[-bash: react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found)

** NOTE ** 
`node -v` gives me v6.10.1
but when i do this:
`npm -v` it says `-bash: npm: command not found`

I thought npm came with node. Is it possible that I do not have npm but have can have nodejs?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installed react-native-cli command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767729/error-when-installed-react-native-cli-command-not-found) and [Path error when installing react-native (Command not found error)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32253981/62576) and [-bash: react-native: command not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33282545/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite can you explain these instructions to me: You have to make sure /usr/local/share/npm/bin is in your PATH to use binaries installed with npm.

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc:

export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
And reload your shell session.

this is found in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm install -g react-native-cli` again. You didn't have npm installed before, when you ran the curl statement, that installed npm, but you now need to install the react-native-cli.

Comment: Trying closing your console and reopening it, then run `npm -v` to see if you've got npm. If it doesn't return an error, run your `sudo nm install -g react-native-cli`. If that doesn't error, then run your `react-native init AwesomeProject`

Comment: that's weird. I have node v6.10.1. But when I check for npm -v it says `-bash: npm: command not found`. I thought npm came with NodeJs. @Greg Billetdeaux

Comment: Looks like it didn't properly get hooked up to your PATH variable? Make sure you properly installed node, and maybe try doing it again.