# react-native: command not found

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am getting `-bash: react-native: command not found error` while creating a react-native project.

Below are the additional info

```
1. brew --version
   homebrew 0.9.9
2  brew info watchman
   watchman `enter code here`stable 4.50
   /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.4.0
3. brew info flow
   stable 0.24.1
   /usr/local/Cellar/flow/0.24.1
4. brew info node
   stable 6.1.0
   /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0
5. npm -version
   3.8.6
6. echo $PATH
/Users/Ashok/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Ashok/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I tried the suggested steps from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found) but I am still getting the same error.

I don't have any "npm" directory which they have specified in the solution

```
Ashoks-MacBook-Pro:share Ashok$ ls
aclocal     doc     info        ruby-build  zsh
autoconf    emacs       man     systemtap
```

But I found npm file exists in the below location.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/etc/bash_completion.d
```

I uninstalled react-native and installed it again but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried `npm i -g react-native-cli` instead of `npm i -g react-native` ?

Comment: i am using "sudo npm install -g react-native-cli"

Comment: Hmm.. not sure but maybe check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found

Comment: As they specified i have to add /usr/local/share/npm/bin in my PATH Variable. but i don't have any npm directory inside /usr/local/share. Thanks @NaderDabit

Comment: when i run `npm config --global get prefix`  i can see **npm** directory in this location -> `/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm`. I have added it to **PATH** variable. Executed `react-native init someApp` command still same error:-(

Answer (score 341, accepted):

*After adding right path to the PATH variable issue is resolved.*

*Below are the steps to find the right path.*

```
1. Enter: npm install -g react-native-cli
output: /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin/react-native ->/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/lib
└── react-native-cli@0.2.0
```

*from above output you can clearly see the path: **/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin/react-native***

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin:$PATH"

react-native init appName

cd appName

react-native run-ios
```

*if you getting **xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl"** at this stage you can reslove using below steps*

*XCode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools -> Choose Xcode 7.2.1*

You can find original solution from [xcrun unable to find simctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108172/xcrun-unable-to-find-simctl)

Thanks to @fbozo

That's It!!!

Comment: No bin folder inside npm!?

Comment: Its not solved permanently. But after opening new terminal, same issue is happening. How to fix this permanently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environmental-variables-in-osx-permanently @Balasubramanian

Comment: This doesn't work if you aren't using sudo to install your npm modules. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124013/280795 for the fix.

Comment: In my case, I had changed my default version of node with NVM, and had forgotten to install react-native again for this new node version. Thank you!

Comment: NOT working, it is not saving this if you restart terminal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently @cd491415

Comment: but installing react-native globally, is not recommended by official docs. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 58):

run this code

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

close your cmd and open  it again

Comment: This suggestion did not fix the problem for me.

Comment: I followed the instructions and it didn't work. But then I had to run also `npm install` close open and it worked.

Answer (score 50):

Try

```
npx react-native
```

if doesn't work install globally

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: `npx react-native` worked for me, thanks.

Comment: npm i -g react-native-cli works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: npx react-native info

Answer (score 47):

After continually running into this problem, and hitting this answer and not having it work..

Assuming you don't run npm as root/sudo (which you shouldn't do!) your npm modules will be installed in [whatever you set your default directory to be](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Assuming you have followed those instructions, and your default directory is ~/.npm-global, then you need to add ~/.npm-global/bin to your path.

This is outlined in those instructions, but for me I added this to .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin
```

Then restart your shell and it will work.

Comment: after being tired of trying almost hundreds of solutions this worked charm on my case, my problem actually was when i close terminal and started again then react-native command was not found.

Answer (score 25):

If who have error , try it with sudo:

> sudo npm install -g react-native-cli

Answer (score 17):

If you're using **yarn**, you may have to run commands with yarn in front. Example:

```
yarn react-native info
```

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue by being a bit silly. I use nvm to manage my different versions of node, and installed react-native into a version of node that was not my default. Upon opening a new shell, I lost my command. :) Switching back of course fixed things.

Comment: Or just globally install it again. Soooo, simple. `$ npm i -g react-native-cli`

Answer (score 9):

If for some strange reasons, the path to `react-native` is not in the `PATH`, you should take note where the `react-native` executable is installed. Generally, the issue with `command not found` is because they are not in `PATH`.

For example, I use `nodenv` and run `npm install -g react-native`

```
/Users/khoa/.nodenv/versions/10.10.0/bin/react-native -> /Users/khoa/.nodenv/versions/10.10.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/wrong-react-native.js
```

So I need to add that to my `PATH`

`export PATH=$HOME/.nodenv/versions/10.10.0/bin:$PATH`

You can verify with `echo $PATH`

Or you can use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to execute local npm modules, for example

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone X'
```

Answer (score 9):

Install react-native globally by using the following command

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue but half of your approach didn't work for me . 
i took the path the way you did :from the output of react-native-cli instal but then manually wrote in ect/pathes with:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

at the end i've added the path from output then ctrl x and y to save .
Only this way worked but big thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 4):

Install `react-native-cli` with `npm install -g react-native-cli`.
You may need to use sudo like `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

Answer (score 3):

At first run this command on your terminal.

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Then create your react-native project by this command.

```
React-native init Project name
```

then move to your project directory by cd command.

Answer (score 2):

According to official documentation, the following command worked for me.

- npx react-native run-android

Link is here

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

I was trying to run by "react-native run-android" command. make sure to have react-native cli installed globally!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has this problem, I had a similar problem to qix, but more nuanced.

New shell terminals would default to a different version of node.
I would change my terminal to the node I wanted, but when the bundle script run, it ran in a new shell, and it got the default version which did not have react-native installed.

I used `nvm alias default x.x.x` so that new shells would inherit the default version I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install yarn
brew install node
brew install watchman
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: why do we need to install this many things to solve a problem so little?
e.g: using nuclear weapons on ant colonies.

Answer (score 1):

Dears,

Please try : npm install -g react-native-cli

If you get an error like Cannot find module ‘npmlog’ you can install npm directly using this command. If the above command run successfully then no need to run this command

curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

#**For_Ubuntu**.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In cmd Administration mode,Run

npm install react-native-cli

Comment: The command you wrote was already used by the person who asked the question, the issue was not related to the command. So please, see the complete discussion related to the solution and ideas for the problem before giving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird, on my side (macOS 10.14), i'm pretty sure my node and npm work but i kept getting command not found only for this particular package. I ended up doing the following:

- Install [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)
- Make sure you enabled remote JS debugging, [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu)
- Run react-native-debugger
- Run your RN app

You can now debug view hierarchy and see console logs in react-native-debugger

Answer (score 0):

I already had `react-native` and `react-native-cli` installed and just had to run:

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after ejecting from expo and forgot to delete the node_modules and reinstall by running `yarn` or `npm install`.

After I did that then run `npx react-native run-android`, it worked fine!

Answer (score -2):

try using react-native --help and see what comes up. try curl

react native library recommendation:

If you get an error like Cannot find module 'npmlog', try installing npm directly: curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: the original problem is that 'react-native' command is not found. 
it is not possible to run react-native --help either

Comment: I ignored the fact that you made a mistake when installing React Native by following the steps in the official Facebook documentation, because I thought you were not a beginner. Now that I'm sure you're a beginner, I can help you better

Answer (score -2):

I did an npm update, runned into the same error but after do an npm install and re-build the app worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).