# React-native command not found ubuntu 16.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04

I install the `react-native`
I install the `nodejs`
I set the paths 
When i do `sudo react-native init AwesomeProject`
give me `react-native: command not found`

Comment: Check whether this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/37193032/5069226

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `npm install -g react-native-cli` first.

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi,i did the same problem,i unistall and install it again but nothing  $ sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
/home/wink/.npm-global/bin/react-native -> /home/wink/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/home/wink/.npm-global/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.3.0 

$ react-native init AwesomeProject
react-native: command not found

Comment: Does the new answer on this page help?
Try adding /home/wink/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/ to the $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3974

The above thread have conversation that solved my problem earlier when i faced the same issue. 
Maybe you will need to add the path manually. Add User/[your-user]/npm/bin to the $PATH.