# React native: Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

Tags: react-native

I had an issue in my React-Native project which was working fine earlier but suddenly it stopped working. Whenever I used the command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I was getting an **error**:

> Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

I **tried** running:

```
react-native android
```

But it said:

> `Unrecognized command 'android' Run react-native --help to see list of
>   all available commands`

After trying:

```
D:\ProjectRoot\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject>react-native eject
```

The error returned was:

> Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   D:\ProjectRoot\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules (48ms)
>   App `name` must be defined in the `app.json` config file to define the
>   project name. It must not contain any spaces or dashes.

This is the app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "description": "A very interesting project.",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.project.first"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: if android folder is missing in root directive then run react-native eject.

Comment: @Khurshid Ansari your solution did not work, as the error is coming: "App name must be defined in the app.json config file to define the project name" even when the name is defined. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml file. Usually, It comes when there is some error in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I raised this question and answered myself as I thought it will help others who are facing similar issue. I struggled a lot to find out the real reason behind it as the error shown in terminal was not precise.

To resolve the issue please upgrade the react-native package.

1. Go to the **Project root**.
2. Upgrade the React native package in the **Command Prompt** by typing :

   `react-native upgrade`.
3. Then Accept to update all the Files by typing `y (Yes)` in the **Command Prompt**.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9312

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris As mentioned in the answer, the react native package can be upgraded on Project root. So, open command prompt and go to the project root. Then upgrade the react native package.

Comment: it is upgraded react-native which i didn't want.

Comment: My working solution is below, none of the above worked for me::

1. Open AVD manager in Android Studio and run a virtual device (you can close AS afterwards)
2. CMD into your project folder and type 'expo start' 
3. Once Expo has started choose option 2 which is "Press a for Android emulator"

It will install expo on the virtual device and you can test from there

Comment: You should consider using the new upgrade tool based on Git. It makes upgrades easier by resolving most conflicts automatically.
To use it:
- Go back to the old version of React Native
- Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade"
- Run "react-native-git-upgrade"
See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html
Your project needs to have a name, declared in package.json, such as "name": "AwesomeApp". Please add a project name. Aborting.

Comment: didn't work in my case ... i have clone this repository -> https://github.com/catalinmiron/react-native-dribbble-app ... but when i run react-native run-android it gives me this error -> error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? I have checked the android folder is inside the project . but it still gives error

Comment: Above didn't work for me. However, I ran the command prompt as admin and it worked!

Comment: Except theres no resolution if you're already upgraded to the latest.

`warn Specified version "0.68.2" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "^0.68.2" semver range. No need to upgrade`

This doesn't fully solve the issue

Answer (score 37):

Open your React Native Project Root Directory and locate android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json .
delete signing-config.json this file 
try again

Or

1)Sometimes if we have older version of react native and some of newly installed packages dose not support older version. Then you have to update the react native project using react-native upgrade command.

2. After done updating current project to new version this error should resolved.

Comment: This works for me, thanks.

Comment: If android\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\release\out\signing-config.json also deleted

Answer (score 24):

I know it is an old question but any of those solutions did not work for me and maybe there are others like me. I solved my problem running this command before `run-android`

```
react-native eject
```

Comment: for some reason this did the trick for me too, I tried the newer version of react native upgrade using "react-native-git-upgrade" as suggested when you run "react-native upgrade" it didn't work for me.

Comment: this command re create android and ios folder in your project

Comment: I think this is the proper answer. Not only because it worked for me, but because from my understanding from the docs, this is the intended way to do it and therefore without other side-effects.

Comment: The `eject` command [has been removed](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275) from `react-native`.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to start the project using command (non-expo):

```
react-native init <your-project-name>
```

If existing folder, then follow:

[react-native eject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-eject)

---

In the latest version of react-native this suggestion comes when you try to issue the command:

```
react-native eject
```

> Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   D:\ProjectRoot\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules (48ms)
>   App `name` must be defined in the `app.json` config file to define the
>   project name. It must not contain any spaces or dashes.

Now when you issue the following command:

```
D:\ProjectRoot\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject>react-native upgrade
```

The following shows up:

> Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   D:\ProjectRoot\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules (56ms)
>   You should consider using the new upgrade tool based on Git. It makes
>   upgrades easier by resolving most conflicts automatically. To use it:
>   - Go back to the old version of React Native
>   - Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade"
>   - Run "react-native-git-upgrade" See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html
>   react-native version in "package.json" doesn't match the installed
>   version in "node_modules". Try running "npm install" to fix this.
>   Aborting.

In the Facebook react-native commands suggestions, there is a clear solution.

These commands check the current version and whether there is update needed or not.

One more solution:

[react-native: Command `run-android` unrecognized. Maybe caused by npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644191/787399)

Please also see:

[Solution to "Expo : cannot find a module LogReporter"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948782/787399)

Comment: Accepted answer for me, +10 rep. to @Abhinav

Answer (score 10):

Open Command Prompt as Administrator and goto the project folder, run android(npx react-native run-android)

Answer (score 9):

I had to restyle my AndroidManifest.xml because I had a syntax error somewhere (I had an extra "/" somewhere). Now it's fixed. Be very careful with your syntax...

Comment: How is this an answer?

Answer (score 8):

I did like this... Worked !!

1. In the CMD Project root run **react-native upgrade**.
2. if you are still getting issues, **make sure** you have **react-native 
   in dependencies json in package.json**, add it if not
3. if you are still getting issues, get the version of react native in cmd using **react-native -v** and check if the value returned in cmd and package.json are same. update the package.json with the value returned in cmd

Here my problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the file: React Native Project Root Directory and locate android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json .

Comment: Or just delete the entire build folder inside the app.

Answer (score 6):

Running Terminal as Administrator in Windows did the trick for me... Other solutions did not work.

Comment: This is only saying thanks to the existing answer by karthik mano, isn't it? If not please make more obvious what additional insight this answer provides.

Answer (score 4):

Open your React Native Project Root Directory and locate android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json

Delete the file and try again.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem today, and none of the solutions worked for me, so I found another one.

**Badly Formatted AndroidManifest.xml will cause this problem**, perhaps you set the splash screen like me today, and didn't formatted AndroidManifest in the correct way

Answer (score 3):

We had this issue because files from **android** folder **gradlew** and **gradlew.bat** (Gradle startup script for the UN*X, Windows respectively) somehow got into the global .gitignore file, and so were not presented on local environments.

Actually running **react-native upgrade** command restore those files, thus fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement, in the case react-native command is not found, you should install react-native CLI:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then you can follow the steps people said above.

More details: [react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

Answer (score 3):

Delete **signing-config.json** next try again **react-native run-android**

signing-config.json file Path : android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json

Answer (score 2):

If you started your project by following

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
create-react-native-app MyReactNative
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm start
```

after this, you can face problem mention above in question So the solution is :

```
npm run eject
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Android Studio (non-expo) and this works for me

```
react-native init <your-project-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, "rm -rf android/app/build/" worked

Run your command with "--verbose". I got the error that it couldn't read a file (in android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/). I deleted this folder, and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I think one more simple thing you could have checked, is if previously you ran the project as different role of a user, like in windows if you ran previously the react-native run-android with an administrator role.

Comment: I had similar issue to the question above and starting the terminal with admin permissions (on Windows) this error went away.

Answer (score 2):

This error simply means you don't have 'android' and 'ios' folders in your root directory of the project. Their location is important.

SOLUTION:-

Open your project folder search for 'android' and iso 'folder', move these folders in your root folder of the project and then start the project with react-native run-android

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My working solution is below, none of the above worked for me:

CD into your project folder and type expo start --android.

Or the long way:

1. Open AVD manager in Android Studio and run a virtual device (you can
   close AS afterwards)
2. CMD into your project folder and type 'expo start'
3. Once Expo has started choose option 2 which is "Press a for Android
   emulator"

It will install expo on the virtual device and you can test from there

Comment: expo start --android worked fine thx

Answer (score 1):

Here, app.json does not have name, but it has expo related config.
So just add name and display name fields in app.json.

app.json (first two lines) :

```
{
"name": "AwesomeProject",
"displayName": "Awesome Project",
"expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "description": "A very interesting project.",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.project.first"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

After this, just run :

$ react-native eject

info Generating the iOS folder.

info Generating the Android folder.

No need to do react-native upgrade.

Comment: actually,  "expo eject" also works better. It gave me options and updated app.json and created android/ios directories.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your cmd with admin priviliges. That solved the same issue for me.
Didnt do "eject" or anything else.

Comment: There are lot of similar answers avaialble for the same question. Instead of  adding your answer, you could just upvote the existing answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've forgotten to add Sudo. Fixed as follows,

```
sudo npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete react native android `build folder` and then retry command `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i didn't had the right permissions for my project folder.

If this is your case just click with the right button on the folder > Properties > Security > Advanced and then change the ownership of the folder to your user, including the subfolders. That should do it

Answer (score 1):

this error maybe happens after generating `.apk` for your project, or when you are in the development stage,  then go to the android folder in the root of your `react-native` app and then check two following paths to delete `signing-config.json` file

**1-**

```
android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json
```

**2-**

```
android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> release -> out -> signing-config.json
```

Answer (score 1):

So if there is anyone having this issue here what worked for me,

```
{
   "name": "ZedMusic",
   "displayName": "zedmusic",
   "expo": {}
}
```

the project name must be outside expo, then run npx react-native eject

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `react-native eject`, I got this error:

```
Both the iOS and Android folders already exist! Please delete `ios` and/or `android` before ejecting.
```

- Delete the `MyProject/android` folder.
- Run `react-native eject` This generated the `android` folder
- Then run `react-native run-android` to build android

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the new upgrade tool based on Git. It makes upgrades easier by resolving most conflicts automatically.
To use it:
- Go back to the old version of React Native
- Run "npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade"
- Run "react-native-git-upgrade"
See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your project with the `expo` command, like `expo init projectname`, then afterwards you have to eject your project:

```
expo eject
```

If you have created you project by `react-native init projectName` then you have to use

```
react-native eject
```

Comment: The eject command has been removed from react-native https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late, I replaced the `Android` folder from a backup file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by killing all instances of java.exe with:
`taskkill /f /im java.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in a project (created with React Native CLI):

[image]

turns out I had a syntax error in my android manifest file (android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).

Answer (score 0):

On windows, my issue had been caused by using `mklink` to create a symlink to another folder of code.

I had:
ProjectDir/common -> ../commonCode

Windows requires you to use mklink in admin mode, so I did.  After that point, I could no longer run `npx react-native run-android` without getting this error, even running in an administrative `cmd` terminal.

Solution for me was to delete the mklink-created symlink and use `ln -s ../commonCode common` in the git bash terminal instead.  This isn't ideal because of how windows handles symlinks, but gets me building again.

Otherwise, I had tried:

- Deleting all of ./android/build and ./android/app/build (didn't help)
- Running `npx react-native run-android` from `cmd` (didn't work)
- Cleaning and reinstalling `node_modules` (no effect)
- Double-checking AndroidManifest.xml for syntax errors (there were none)
- `npx react-native eject` (eject isn't a command anymore)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally deleted `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `android/app/src/main` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project as an **administrator**.

```
react-native run-android
```

Attention: make sure you have reactive-native cli installed.

To install reactive-native cli on windows, run.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a matter of stopping a firebase functions serve which was disallowing building or cleaning. So you may check if there is no serve you are running inside the project directory

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resolve this issue by Go to **node_modules** folder then Go to **glob** folder and then Go to **common.js** in this file find (**options.allowWindowsEscape = ture**) now you have to change the true into false as this (**options.allowWindowsEscape = false**) Now hope your error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

go into the node_modules folder, find glob, and open the common.js file. in search for options.allowWindowsEscape ,  you will find options.allowWindowsEscape = true, change it to false and it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For react-native cli, in an instance where your android folder is missing

1. Run `npm install react-native-eject --save-dev`
2. Go to the rn-fetch-blob package folder in node_modules and delete react-native.config.js file.
3. Run `npx react-native eject`, your android folder would be generated
4. Run `npm run android`, your app should start.

That's all!!! This should also work for IOS