# react-native run-android issue - error Android project not found

Tags: android, react-native

I create a react native app in C9. Now, I want to develop this app on my local machine with android settings. I downloaded the project.

```
cd myProjectFolder
react-native start
npm install
react-native run-android
```

Also, I add a project name in package.json.

The error is below:

> error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Comment: Same situation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723958/react-native-android-project-not-found-maybe-run-react-native-android-first

Answer (score 0):

If android project/folder does not exit in your root project then run :

```
react-native eject
```

Comment: The `eject` command [has been removed](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275) from `react-native`.

Comment: yes in latest version of react native cli, eject command has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after I ruan `./gradlew clean`. Tried serval methods but vain. Then I ran `./gradlew` in the Android directory. It worked for me.

```
// Android
./gradlew
```