# React Native Android Project Not Found

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error.

```
error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

There is no solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723958/react-native-android-project-not-found-maybe-run-react-native-android-first) link.

````
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2"
  }
```
Package.json file
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix it without reinstalling, just go into the `node_modules` folder, find `glob`, and open the `common.js` file.
in line 114 you will find `options.allowWindowsEscape = true`, change it to `false` and it will work perfectly!

Comment: thanks albert. you save my day. I tested all other solutions and not worked. but yours ❤

Comment: I am glad to read it!

Answer (score 8):

Hi i have solved with 3 steps.

1. Clear node_modules
2. add this to package.json

   ```
   "resolutions": {
   "glob": "7.2.0" }
   ```
3. And reinstall with `npm install`

If this is not work please install glob with `npm i glob@7.2.0`

Comment: Unbelievable. It forced me to install Glob. Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure it out all day.

Comment: Glad to hear that. With new version of react-native glob comes with 7.2.2 and it is pretty new version. I think (hope) it will solved quickly and we will not have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can install glob `npm i glob`

Its works for me.