# reactive-native cli error creating new projects "Android project not found."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

When I try to run a react native project with the command `react-native run-android` the following exception is a displayed:

> "Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location."

The first two projects I created ran correctly, but since then every new project created displays the above exception when I try to run them in the emulator. Can someone help clarify why I am encountering this exception?

Comment: Refer to the answers in this question to see if it can help with the above: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43723958/11543023

Comment: I think this is because of the new version glob package in the current react-native dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes after the glob package version 7.2.2 was released. Version 7.2.2 has **allowWindowsEscape = true**

```js
options.allowWindowsEscape = false // This should be false
```

However, you can add the 7.2.0 version in package.json.

Follow the below steps to fix this:

- Delete node_modules
- add this to package.json "resolutions": { "glob": "7.2.0" }
- Reinstall node_modules with npm install

If this does not work try the below command

"npm i glob@7.2.0"

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks!!

Comment: can u help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261949/react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object-error