# React native CLI : Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Tags: react-native

when I tried to run the react native project on android by command `npm run android`
I got this error:

> The android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside the 'android' folder), consider setting `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location.info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: The same question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72249777/1386780 You can try the above fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. To resolve the issue please upgrade the react-native package.
2. Go to the Project root.
3. Upgrade the React native package in the Command Prompt by typing `react-native upgrade`
4. Then Accept to update all the Files by typing y (Yes) in the Command Prompt.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9312
and also use the command : npx react-native run-android