# $react-native init AwesomeProject getting an error react-native command not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am very new to React native.

Following the documentation, after putting the command `$react-native init AwesomeProject` I'm getting: `react-native command not found`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

Comment: check the path. Make sure that the path you using is same as where the binaries are installed. Feel free to know how.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `npm i -g react-native-cli`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19734943)

Comment: As he didn't ask a question, I thought that a solution could fit here, sorry

Answer (score -1):

You should run this command to set path

`export PATH="/Users/ots/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"`

Then you can run
`react-native init MyNewProject`