# React native - missing srcipt: ios

Tags: react-native, package.json, expo

How to run react native app in iOS Stimulator?

I'm using `npm run ios` but I'm getting this error `missing srcipt: ios`

How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can run your project with just simple

```
react-native run-ios
```

And if you want to run on any particular simulator device run this

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s" // Check your available devices
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found check this may b you are missing something while setting up react native

Comment: Oh, I think because I'm using `npm install exp` and `exp init myproject` to create the project, so that it's not react native project? how to use exp and react-native at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we have `package.json` with any command line scripts, for example:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll",
    "dev": "exp start --dev --lan",
    "build-android": "exp build:android",
    "build-ios": "exp build:ios"
},
```

In your case, I am not sure from which source you initialized or cloned your project. But you will need to add and you can add without any issue the missing scripts.
You can label them by anything, e.g. `"test"` can be named by `"mytest"`.

The example I have given above, you can see command `exp`, this is a module that you will need to install globally in order to run this command.

using `npm install -g exp` command. Then you can run the custom added scripts.

Find anything confusing, ask again.

Comment: is that mean I have to copy the scripts and paste it on my package.json. Then run `npm install -g exp` on terminal?

Comment: Yes, during development we use `dev` script that you see in example, so you can run on your emulator or mobile device. Now if you want to make a final build `.apk` for *Android* and `.ipa` for *iOS* then we use `build-ios` script to make a final build for developed app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `react-native run-ios`?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios.html

If that doesn't work, you can always open project-directory/app/ios/[your-project-name].xcodeproj in xcode, and run the simulator in xcode directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue which is (build failded) and after i entered following commands for my current workspace's terminal.

1-`cd ios`
2-`bundle install`
3- `bundle exec pod install`
After those steps i came across this (react native missing script) then i followed this steps.

1-Open the Xcode and open your project with Xcode.
2-Press the start the active scheme button (looks like a play button)
Then waited,it works.