# "exp: command not found" How do I add expo cli to path?

Tags: macos, react-native, expo

I installed the expo cli with

```
npm i -g exp
```

then I run

```
exp
```

and I get

```
-bash: exp: command not found
```

I'm guessing I didn't add exp to path. So how do I do this properly? Nothing I've tried so far works.

Comment: I have found the solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found) is the solution for react-native cli. Replace react-native with expo (exp).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

Comment: try `export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/.bin`

Answer (score 28):

You should try `npx expo init <your_app_name>` to test.

It worked for me.

Comment: sometimes things work and your don't even care why

Answer (score 22):

This suggested 3 steps solution worked for me:

1. First check if `~/.npm-global/bin` is in your path: `echo $PATH`. If it isn’t there, you will need to add it to the path.
2. Open up `~/.bash_profile` then add the following line to the bottom: `export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin`
3. Finally, back in the shell, type: `source ~/.bash_profile`

Hopefully that will have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 22):

**1. Find the path where expo is globally installed by npm:**

```html
npm bin -g
```

**2. Add path from Step 1 to paths file:**

```html
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

**3. Restart the Terminal**

Answer (score 12):

try `sudo npm install --global expo-cli`
this worked for me.

```
➜  MobileDev git:(campaigns-responsive) ✗ expo whoami
› Not logged in, run expo login to authenticate
➜  MobileDev git:(campaigns-responsive) ✗ expo init App
✔ Choose a template: › blank                 a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
✔ Downloaded and extracted project files.
 Using npm to install packages.
✔ Installed JavaScript dependencies.

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd App
- npm start # you can open iOS, Android, or web from here, or run them directly with the commands below.
- npm run android
- npm run ios
- npm run web
```

Comment: Better change access permissions to your dir with global node modules by chmod / chown. Even better install node by nvm.

Comment: `sudo npm install --global expo-cli` --worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I also had a hard time getting expo command to work on Mac.  Here are the steps I took to get it working.

`npm root -g` shows the directory the global modules are installed in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.7.0/lib/node_modules
```

That directory might be different for you. After confirming expo is in there, edit `~/.bash_profile` and add the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.7.0/bin
```

Save & exit, then run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Now the `expo` command should function as intended.

Comment: Only a working solution for me! Search a lot, tried a lot. This is the only fix. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

`exp` was [replaced](https://blog.expo.io/expo-cli-2-0-released-a7a9c250e99c) with `expo`

To install Expo CLI, just run `npm install -g expo-cli` (or `yarn global add expo-cli`, whichever you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

Following on this issue, I found I had multiple global folders so I started using a .npm-global folder as shown here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

And now it's all clean and in control.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

```
-bash: expo: command not found
```

It turns out the command to install expo
 `npm install -g expo-cli` was referencing an older version of node on my machine; when checked using `npm root -g`.

So I had to uninstall nvm/node, deleted any remnant folders & files of `.nvm` and shortcuts for `nvm` in `/usr/local`. Then reinstalled node and ran `npm install -g expo-cli` again.

That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

If you're using git bash on windows, add npm path to your system path variables. Generally located on this location:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Then open the bash and command `npm start`. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting this in my `PATH` environment variable / user variable:

```
C:\Users\{userName}\node_modules\.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn expo start
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> npx create-expo-app **project-name**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
npx create-expo-app <appname>
```

instead and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).