# -bash: expo: command not found

Tags: bash, command, expo

I've seen other posts with this issue (cf : ["exp: command not found" How do I add expo cli to path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775496/exp-command-not-found-how-do-i-add-expo-cli-to-path))

But still i cannot resolve this issue...

here is a screenshot of my config. [image: Screen terminal]

Please someone have a solution? of maybe i did bad ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using ZSH, in this case you need to configure your path in `~/.zshrc` file and not in the `.bash_profile` that only will be load by `bash`

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin' >> ~/.zshrc` and then reload the config with `source .zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but dont seems works...   https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/11/paj5.png

Comment: Yes, you are right! I've edit my answer, you need to change the `~` to `$HOME` variable in the `PATH`.

Comment: thanks :) But sadly it's still doesnt work, when i try to source, i have the issue : sudo: source: command not found. i become crazy haha

Comment: Weird! I'm guessing your are with some problem in your terminal config... the `source` is only to reload your actual config, but you can simply close your terminal and open it again. The ~/.zshrc by default is huge file with comments and others config.

Comment: Weird.. as you say.  i dont know what to do then !