# zsh: command not found: react-native - MacOS

Tags: macos, react-native

I am trying to start react-native but I get the following error `zsh: command not found: react-native` when I write `react-native init firstApp`
.

I tried the following guide: [react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

But I have two main issue:

**First**
I do not understand which path to use/export

React-native has been installed here:

```
/Users/cisco/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/cisco/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/wrong-react-native.js
```

**Second**

In the guide it is written to run:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin:$PATH"   
react-native init appName  
cd appName   
react-native run-ios
```

I do not get how to:

**1)** What to write after `export PATH=`

**2)** Should I add my path somewhere? If yes, how can I do so?
I tried running `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile` to add my path.

Inside it I have:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/cisco/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/cisco/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/cisco/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/cisco/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Once you help me in finidng out the right path do add, can I simply add it in the file below the line `# <<< conda init <<<?`

Comment: did you tried to give full path for react-native

Comment: did you install the react-native-cli - `npm install -g react-native-cli`?

Comment: Yes, I did install `npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: Well, doing `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli` did the job for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it!

Steps:

1. Run `npm list -g | head -n 1`

It will give you a path like/similar to the following: `/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/.npm-packages/lib`

2. Change that path by substituting `/lib` with `/bin:$PATH` so that you get: `/Users/cisco/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH`
3. Run `export PATH="/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Its fixed my issue in Apple M2 MacBook Pro, Thank you so much for your solution @Magofoco

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using zsh. You can add `export PATH=/Users/cisco/.npm-packages/bin/react-native:$PATH` in ~/.zshrc

Comment: I did the following `stt ~/.zshrc` and add the line `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin:$PATH` but I get the same message.

Comment: can you try with this `/Users/cisco/.npm-packages/bin/react-native` i edited my answer

Comment: can you confirm that this file `/Users/cisco/.npm-packages/bin/react-native` is exist?

Answer (score 0):

This operation work for me very well. Just follow the instruction below.

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run

```sh
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```