# How do I open react-native app in emulator?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a react-native app that I have just ejected from expo to a bare react-native app.

I can run `yarn react-native run-android` without any errors and even opens my android emulator however, I can't see my app available within the emulator.

Should this open automatically or should I see it available in the app draw?

How can I start my app within the emulator?

[image]

note: the `Who Am I` app is not it. It's my built version via expo before I ejected.

Answer (score 1):

The command should be `react-native run-android` not `yarn react-native run-android` unless you defined the script `react-native run-android` as itself in your package.json.

Then the app should start by itself in the emulator, but you have to run `react-native start` to use it.

`react-native run-android` installs the app on the emulator so you should be able to find the launch icon of your app inside the emulator

Using `react-native run-android` without **exactly** one device (one emulator or one real device) leads to an error (`Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected.` in case none is connected) thus if you don't have a real device connected your emulator is detected.

Comment: I'm using yarn so I need to prefix with `yarn` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303085/3528590

Comment: I'm using yarn too ;)

Comment: I have just tried with `npx react-native run-android` and get the same thing

Comment: Do you have react-native installed globally via NPM or via Yarn?

Comment: yes I have but I run react-native with `yarn android` since I have in the script part of my `package.json` this line:  `"android": "react-native run-android"`

Comment: yeah same with me. `yarn android` runs `react-native run-android` which is the same as `yarn react-native run-android`

Comment: When you run yarn android, nothing happens on the emulator and you don't get any error message in the terminal? And no real device is connected to your computer?

Comment: I wasn't running `react-native start` as well. So now when I run `react-native run-android` I get `Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version`

Comment: Normally this error is not related to react-native start but yes it's not very clear at first that you install the app with run-android and actually run it with start. The error is now something else, you probably just don't have Gradle installed